# Найти общие элементы во вложенных списках

Tags: python, list

Цель такова: найти общие элементы среди элементов в `list`.

Допустим, имеется список:

```
x = [['c', 'p', 'd', 'a', 'b'], ['p', 'v', 'b'], ['s', 'p', 'v', 'b']]
```

Нужно сделать что-то такое, чтобы найти общие элементы в листах, которые в листе. Аналогично `x[0] & x[1] & x[2]` (возвращает `{'p', 'b'}`).

*Лист используется не просто так, а потому, что неизвестно, сколько элементов в нем будет (от 1 до n).*

Помогите найти самое простое решение, спасибо.

Comment: Внутри одного листа могут быть одинаковые элементы?

Comment: Проще всего преобразовать списки во множества и сделать их пересечение.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение через [set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
>>> x = [['c', 'p', 'd', 'a', 'b'], ['p', 'v', 'b'], ['s', 'p', 'v', 'b']]
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, x))
{'b', 'p'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
common = set(x[0])
common.intersection_update(*[set(i) for i in x[1:]])
```